# ng-show value change to true false but ng-show does not work

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to show/hide the division based on the selection of type(using the radio button).

Following is the code for the radio buttons :

```
<div class="col-md-7 checkbox-inline" >
    <label><input type="radio" id="authentication-type" ng-model="authenticationType" name="authenticationType" checked value="itas">ITAS</label> 
    <label><input type="radio" id="authentication-type" ng-model="authenticationType" name="authenticationType" value="ldap">LDAP</label>
</div>
```

**The non-working version**

Here i am trying to remove the case sensitivity while comparison. The value of the expressions

```
{{ (authenticationType | lowercase)   == 'itas' }}
{{ (authenticationType | lowercase)   == 'ldap' }}
```

is changing but the but the show/hide on the following div's is not working

```
<div ng-show="{{ (authenticationType | lowercase)   == 'itas' }}">ITAS</div>
<div ng-show="{{ (authenticationType | lowercase)   == 'ldap' }}">LDAP</div>
```

**The working version**

Here i am doing simple comparison and it is working fine.

```
<div ng-show="{{ (authenticationType | lowercase)   === 'itas' }}">ITAS</div>
<div ng-show="{{ (authenticationType | lowercase)   === 'ldap' }}">LDAP</div>
```

I am able to proceed further but i just want to know why this is happening. If anyone can put some light on it that will be very nice.

Comment: `ng-show` directive directly take an expression without `{{}}`(interpolation) directive.. It would look like `ng-show="(authenticationType | lowercase)   === 'itas'"`

Comment: @Pankaj can you please explain this a little.

Comment: this problem occurs if your are using version less than 1.2.0 check with latest version

Comment: @Pravin version is not the problem. I have checked it with 1.5.8 and it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on Pankaj’s answer, `ng-show` takes an expression (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow):

> The ngShow directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on
>   the expression provided to the ngShow attribute.

The keyword here is *expression*.  i.e., `ng-show` takes a javascript expression to determine whether to show or hide the element.  I would normally have written this like:

```
<div ng-show="authenticationType.toLowerCase() == 'itas'">ITAS</div>
<div ng-show="authenticationType.toLowerCase() == 'ldap'">LDAP</div>
```

n.b. here epxressions are different from `{{ }}` which is called markup.  You can compare this to the `ng-src` directive which takes markup and not an expression:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc.